# Json.net deserialization array of interfaces

Tags: c#, json, interface, polymorphism, json.net

I'm getting a "type is interface, cannot be instanciated" deserialization error with json.net even though I am specifying type on the object I'm trying to deserialize

```
private static JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { 
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };

/// <summary>
/// Returns an object created from the jObject and placed in a stub object
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <param name="jObj"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T FromJObject<T>(JToken jObj)
{
    if (jObj == null)
    {
        jObj = new JObject();
    }
    if (jObj is JValue)
    {
        return (T)((JValue)jObj).Value;
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jObj.ToString(), settings);
    }
 }
```

this is jObj

```
{
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Name",
  "JsonMapEnum": 0,
  "Validations": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "$type": "JsonMap.Default.JValidation, JsonMap"
    }
  ],
  "JSType": 3,
  "SubJsonMapEnum": -1,
  "$type": "JsonMap.Default.JAttribute, JsonMap"
}
```

This is the error

`Could not create an instance of type JsonMap.Interfaces.IValidation. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantated. Path 'Validations[0].Id'`

It looks like it's trying to turn Id into a Validation object. Why?

these are the interfaces implemented by my types

```
public interface IJsonMap
{
    long Id { get; set; }
    String Name { get; set; }
    LazyEnum JsonMapEnum { get; set; }
}

public interface IAttribute : IJsonMap
{
    IEnumerable<IValidation> Validations { get; set; }
    LazyEnum JSType { get; set; }
    LazyEnum SubJsonMapEnum { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidation : IJsonMap
{
    IEnumerable<IArgument> Arguments { get; set; }
}
```

this is the call

```
FromJObject<JAttribute>(CreationJObj)
```

JAttribute implements IAttribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, "$type" has to be the first property in the String literal in order for the type to be caught by the type name handler. I imagine this is because The deserializer isn't checking for the existence of $type, it simply uses the json string reader, and upon finding the first property without the type being set, it fails out.

Here's the method I created to ensure $type is always first

```
    private static JToken ReorderJToken(this JToken jTok)
    {
        if (jTok is JArray)
        {
            var jArr = new JArray();
            foreach (var token in jTok as JArray)
            {
                jArr.Add(token.ReorderJToken());
            }
            return jArr;
        }
        else if( jTok is JObject)
        {
            var jObj = new JObject();
            foreach(var prop in (jTok as JObject).Properties().OrderBy(x=> x.Name))
            {
                prop.Value = prop.Value.ReorderJToken();
                jObj.Add(prop);
            }
            return jObj;
        }
        return jTok;
    }
```

Comment: `Apparently, "$type" has to be the first property`. No need for it. Suppose you are the author of the serializer, would you use `dict["$type"]` or `list[0]`

Comment: Fine, but have a method that reorganizes you're properties , I had to create a utility method for just that reason, and it was not obvious in any way that this was a requirement. When dealing with browsers and client side json creation, this doesn't seem like an out of left field use case.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I am eternally grateful to JamesNK for creating the tool, all I'm saying is that this is unexpected behavior, sorry for letting my frustration make me seem smarmy.

Answer (score 0):

Well clearly it cannot infer the proper type based off the arguments you're feeding it. Without more context of how it's called I can't make what you have work. However, if you call it with an object cast to the interfaces type it will not work. With the definition you have `FromObject` must always be called with `T` is the type of a class. First thing to do is make sure you never try to call the method where `T` is equal to `typeof(IOneOfMyInterfaces)` because this is guaranteed to fail. If that doesn't fix it I would try calling a different version of the deserialize method;

```
IMyInterface obj = (IMyInterface)serializer.Deserialize(validatingReader, t);
```

This works where validatingReader is a `JsonReader` and `t` is the `Type` of the class object implementing `IMyInterface`. I'm currently using it for generic deserialization with json schemas for validating json correctness.

Comment: oops, sorry, forgot to include that. JTransformer.FromJObject<JAttribute>(CreationJObj)